# Jquery slideshow working locally but not on server

Tags: jquery, ftp

on my site http://filthypolitics.com  there is supposed to be a slide show in the background but it no longer works when i upload it to my ftp, but everything works perfectly locally on my computer. can anyone help? my hosting is dreamhost

Answer (score 2):

If you check your console, you'll notice that it's unable to load 6 different images. Perhaps you forgot to upload the slideshow's images?